# the number 2 and 3 words

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose there is a list of the most popular words of a particular year. The most popular one is called Word of the Year. How do we refer to the second and third most popular ones?

> The number 2 and 3 words

or

> The numbers 2 and 3 words

or

> Number 2 and 3 (words)

or

> Numbers 2 and 3 (words)

or

> The number 2 and 3 of the Word of the Year

or

> The numbers 2 and 3 of the Word of the Year

Comment: Why not "the second and third most popular words" as in the first paragraph

Comment: I've seen the following use of cardinal numbers in reference to rankings: In those 10 years, Texas gained 732,800 private sector jobs, far ahead of the number two and three states, Arizona (90,200) and Nevada (90,000).

Answer (score 1):

You could also call them the first two runners up